# How to filter a dataframe based on column values(multiple values through a arraybuffer) in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

In scala/spark code I have 1 Dataframe which contains some rows:

```
col1      col2
Abc       someValue1 
xyz       someValue2
lmn       someValue3
zmn       someValue4
pqr       someValue5
cda       someValue6
```

And i have a variable of `ArrayBuffer[String]` which contains `[xyz,pqr,abc]`;

I want to filter given dataframe based on given values in arraybuffer at *col1*.

In SQL it would be like:

```
select * from tableXyz where col1 in("xyz","pqr","abc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your dataframe:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("abc","someValue1"),
                            ("xyz","someValue2"),
                            ("lmn","someValue3"),
                            ("zmn","someValue4"),
                            ("pqr","someValue5"),
                            ("cda","someValue6")))
                 .toDF("col1","col2") 

+----+----------+
|col1|      col2|
+----+----------+
| abc|someValue1|
| xyz|someValue2|
| lmn|someValue3|
| zmn|someValue4|
| pqr|someValue5|
| cda|someValue6|
+----+----------+
```

Then you can define an UDF to filter the dataframe based on array's values:

```
val array = ArrayBuffer[String]("xyz","pqr","abc") 

val function: (String => Boolean) = (arg: String) => array.contains(arg)
val udfFiltering = udf(function)

val filtered = df.filter(udfFiltering(col("col1")))
filtered.show()
+----+----------+
|col1|      col2|
+----+----------+
| abc|someValue1|
| xyz|someValue2|
| pqr|someValue5|
+----+----------+
```

Alternately you can register your dataframe and sql-query it by SQLContext:

```
var elements = ""
array.foreach { el => elements += "\"" + el + "\"" + "," }
elements = elements.dropRight(1)    
val query = "select * from tableXyz where col1 in(" + elements + ")"

df.registerTempTable("tableXyz")
val filtered = sqlContext.sql(query)
filtered.show()
+----+----------+
|col1|      col2|
+----+----------+
| abc|someValue1|
| xyz|someValue2|
| pqr|someValue5|
+----+----------+
```